Point estimate of exponential distribution
Let $X_1, ..., X_n \sim Exp(\lambda)$ What's the probability $p$ that $X > 1$ for $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$.
$p$ should be $e^{-\lambda*1}$
I want to use only the following method for point estimate $p$:
From the sampling use only Bernoulli values where $Y_i = 1$ if $X_i > 1$, else $Y_i = 0$. So we know that each $Y_i$ is $Ber(p)$ distribution.
How can I estimate $p$?
Especially I want to investigate for values: $\lambda = 1.5$ and $n = 4$

Since $Y_1$ is an unbiased estimator of $p$, the exercise suggests using a Rao-Blackwell improvement by conditioning on $\bar Y$.

Note that if the $X_i$'s can be used as well, an improvement is to condition on $\bar X$.

You can use maximum likelihood estimation (or anything else that uses a likelihood, like various Bayesian MCMC methods). Your likelihood is simply the usual one for a binomial distribution, just with $\pi$ replaced by the probability $\pi:=e^{-\lambda x}$ from the exponential distribution.
Or, using the log-likelihood $\log L \propto y \log \pi + (n-y) \log(1-\pi) := - y \lambda x + (n-y) \log(1-e^{-\lambda x})$ (where $y:= \sum_i y_i$).
Note that there's numerically stable versions of the $\log(1-e^z)$ function that you may wish to use.
